# ¿Como recargar pagina de un webview Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Muy buen dia!
Tengo una pagina con 3 botones que cargo en mi webview, uno de esos botones tiene el evento "`onclick="location.reload();"`, el problema esta que en versiones android 7.0 en adelante la aplicacion se detiene y se cierra la app, y en versiones anteriores el boton funciona perfectamente, alguien sabe porque pasa este error?

Aclaro que necesito hacerlo desde la pagina web, no desde un botón en android.

Comment: Ya intentaste con: <a href="javascript:location.reload()">Actualizar página</a>

Comment: Si, ya lo hice, siempre se cierra la app